# Solving Stochastic Differential Equation using integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Now I try to **solve the following stochastic differential equation**:
$$
\frac{dX_t}{X_t} = \left(-1+\frac{1}{2}t + (\beta - 1)\frac{X_t-1}{t}\right) dt + \alpha dB_t,
$$
where $\alpha, \beta$ and $X_0=x_0$ are some constants.

**Here what I have tried.**

By multiplying integrating factor 
$$
  F_t = \exp(-\alpha B_t + \alpha^2 t / 2),
$$
we have 
$$
\frac{dY_t}{dt}=F_t F_t^{-1} Y_t \left(f'(t) + (\beta-1)\frac{F_t^{-1}Y_t-1}{t} \right)  \\
 = \left\{ \left(-1+\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{\beta-1}{t}\right) + (\beta - 1)  e^{\alpha B_t-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}t}\frac{Y_t}{t} \right\} Y_t
$$
for $Y_t=F_t X_t$. Then this equation is just a deterministic differential equation.
For the homogeneous equation, we can use seperation of variable to solve
$$
\frac{1}{Y_t}\frac{dY_t}{dt} + (1-\beta)e^{\alpha B_t-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}t}\frac{Y_t}{t}=0
$$
with
$$
Y_t=\left((1-\beta)\int e^{\alpha B_t - \frac{\alpha^2}{2}t}dt + C\right)^{-1}.
$$
But for the inhomotegenous equation
$$
\frac{1}{Y_t}\frac{dY_t}{dt} + (1-\beta)e^{\alpha B_t-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}t}\frac{Y_t}{t}=-1+\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{\beta-1}{t},
$$
I have trouble to solve.
Can anyone help me with the above SDE?

Comment: What is exactly $\beta_t$ ?

Comment: $\beta$ is just a constant like 0.5. If you mean $B_t$, it is one path of standard Brownian motion.

Comment: I see then your equation is a Bernouilli's equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dY_t}{dt}= \left\{ \left(-1+\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{\beta-1}{t}\right) + (\beta - 1)  e^{\alpha B_t-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}t}\frac{Y_t}{t} \right\} Y_t$$
Looks like a Bernouilli's equation of the form
$$y'+\alpha(t)y=\beta (t) y^n$$

Here you have $n=2$. Divide by $Y^2(t)$ both side. 
$$\frac{dY_t}{dt}\frac 1 {Y^2_t}= \left\{ \left(-1+\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{\beta-1}{t}\right)\frac 1 {Y_t} + (\beta - 1)  e^{\alpha B_t-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}t}\frac{1}{t} \right\} $$

Then substitute $Z(t)=\frac 1 {Y_t}, Z'(t)=-\frac {Y'_t} {Y^2_t}$. 
$$Z'(t)+ \left(-1+\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{\beta-1}{t}\right)Z(t)= -\left\{ (\beta - 1)  e^{\alpha B_t-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}t}\frac{1}{t} \right\} $$

The equation is now a first order linear DE. Use any techniques you know to solve it ( integrating factor ). But it's not going to be easy to integrate not because of the DE but because od the functions that  are really complicated.